# text-changing function does not execute

Tags: python

I have tried to change some values on an script.txt using a python program.

So, the following function makes that work:

```
def textx(x,y):
    with open("script.txt","r") as f:
        newline = []
        for word in f.readlines():
            newline.append(word.replace(x, y))
    with open("script.txt","w") as f:
        for line in newline:
            f.writelines(line)
    return
```

Where `x` and `y` must quoted numbers, i.e., for example `"2"` and `"3"`.
Since I need to make a loop over many values of `x` and `y`, I created a list of quoted numbers as follows:

```
def quotes(x):
    Q = '"%s"'%x
    return Q;

SS = list();
QS = list();

for i in range(4):
    SS.append(i)

for j in SS:
    i = quotes(j)
    QS.append(i)
```

But when I try to run the function `textx()` as follows:

```
textx(QS[0], QS[3])
```

The program runs without any error, but I expect in the `script.txt` file that the `0`-value will be changed to `3`, but this does not happen. So, how I can make the `text`x function run properly with the elements of the `QS` list?

Comment: Let see if I understand it correctly: You want to replace all `0` with `3` in a text file, correct?

Comment: Hi Hai Vu, in this case yes!, but I need to do this using the list QS. That because the code above its just a draft, the real code will be have a bigger list of complicated numbers and then just one number will be change on the entire code.

Comment: You don't need those `;` characters you just added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably because the strings you put into the `QS` list *include* the two doubles quote characters `"`, so the call to the string `replace()` method fails and doesn't do anything.

If you change the `quotes()` function to:

```
def quotes(x):
    Q = '%s' % x
    return Q
```

It should then work. It also means you don't really need to have separate `SS` and `QS` lists because you could just create the one list needed to drive the `textx()` function with this one-liner (assuming the new list is named `new_list`):

```
new_list = [str(i) for i in range(4)]
```

And then use it instead of `QS` to call `textx()`.
In other words:

```
textx(new_list[0], new_list[3])
```